# ArangoDB ACIDity

Tags: transactions, arangodb

I have been reading the ArangoDB documentation and I am getting an impression that transactionality and thus ACID properties are only supported in a single server setup or in a clustered setup as long as none of the collections are sharded. I am hoping that I am misreading the documentation, and perhaps someone could shine some light on my misunderstandings.

Here are the links to the documents which lead me to my conclusions:
https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/aql/high-level-operations/remove/
https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/aql/high-level-operations/update/
.../replace/
.../insert/
.../upsert/

All of them have a statement in the following form
(substitute removal with appropriate AQL action listed in the links above):

> On a single server, the document removal is executed transactionally
> in an all-or-nothing fashion. For sharded collections, the entire
> remove operation is not transactional.

And so, if I am reading this correctly - if the collection grows in size such that it must be sharded, then none of the CRUD operations can be performed in a transactional manner, and thus ACID properties can no longer be retained.

Would my understanding be also correct, that transactionality and ACID properties could be retained in a clustered ArangoDB server installation, provided that none of the collections have to be sharded, however, the collections could be spread across multiple nodes retaining their entirety per node, and none of the nodes would have to have all the collections present on them.

My thanks go out to anyone in advance who can shine any light on this topic.

Null

Answer (score 2):

Transactional security in a cluster is on par with other solutions, with the added bonus of multi-document and -collection queries being ACID as well if they are not distributed over multiple nodes.

- Using a single instance of ArangoDB, multi-document / multi-collection queries are guaranteed to be fully ACID. This is more than many other NoSQL database systems support.
- In an ArangoDB cluster, single-document operations are also fully ACID.
- Multi-document / multi-collection queries in a cluster are not ACID. This is equally the case with the database systems of our competitors, such as MongoDB, OrientDB, Neo4j and so on. We actively pursue the goal to support fully ACID transactions in a cluster however, which will set ArangoDB apart from other database solutions.
- For non-sharded collections in a cluster, the transactional properties of a single server apply. That means, multi-document queries are ACID if the collection has a single shard and thus resides on a single DBserver.

Comment: Thank you for the response and the confirmation of my interpretation of the docs.  
  
I am not quite sure I agree with the following statement in respect of Neo4j:  
> Multi-document / multi-collection queries in a cluster are not ACID. This is equally the case with the database systems of our competitors, such as MongoDB, OrientDB, Neo4j and so on.  
  
If I understand it correctly Neo4j does not really have collections, but rather labels. And my understanding (perhaps invalid) is that Neo4j does support ACID properties for multi document changes within same transaction.

Comment: Also, Neo4j does not presently have a concept of sharding per se, and as such I do not believe it would be apples to apples comparison of Neo4j and Arango DB ACIDity in this space.  

I do agree though, that were ArangoDB to achieve ACID properties in a sharded and multidocument setting, it would stand out among the competition.  

And, with great enthusiasm, I wish all the best of luck for you guys working on achieving this.